# Android: Can I save more than one SharedPreference entry to a file?

Tags: android, list, android-activity, sharedpreferences, shared

This is the problem:
I have a form for inputting names, then saves it, then displays it in another activity. But once I try to enter another name, the previous name is overwritten by the new name.

Is there a way to set these names up to list themselves one after another without overwriting each other in SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do it like Konstantin Pribluda suggested, or you might think of using the SQLite, if you have a lot of names you want to store (e.g. if creating a history of typed in names). That way you can store unlimited values for the same key and retrieve them as a list/cursor. 
But of course that's overkill if you only have 2-3 names…

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up using SQLite and have it working. Now I have new problem. I'm building a cash register. Entering info works fine, but I'm having trouble trying to get combine the values ($) of each bill into a textview to show the total of all bills added together. Any suggestions on how to make this possible or a specific tutorial on the web?

Comment: @Paul If this answer was helpful, you might want to accept it. Your new question should be an actual new question (if you've not already asked it by now).

Answer (score 1):

You can as long as they have distinct names.  Ig you need multiple values for same name, you can store JSON array or use some form of prefix / suffix solution to provide unique names

Answer (score 0):

you can also save a [Set of Strings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) in the SharedPreferences.